# Get instance of JQuery UI popup

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, instance

I am creating a JQuery UI popup this way:

```
function ShowJQueryStandardDialog(searchTarget, title, width, height, closeFunction)
{
    var $dialog = $('<div id="dialogDIV"><iframe id="dialogIFrame" frameborder="no" scrolling="auto" src="' + searchTarget + '" width="' + (width - 50) + 'px" height="' + (height - 50) + 'px"></iframe></div>');

    $dialog.dialog(
    {
        modal: true,
        title: title,
        show: 'slide',
        width: width,
        height: height,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        close: function (event, ui)
        {
            if (typeof closeFunction === 'function') closeFunction();
        }
    });
}
```

I then want to get the instance of the popup elsewhere in the code so I can close it. I tried:

```
var $dialog = $('#dialogDIV');
var $dialog = $('.ui-dialog');
var $dialog = $('.ui-dialog-content');
```

But it returns empty object. Note that if I put the above code in the `close` method of the dialog, it works fine. Shall I conclude that I can't access the popup from outside its init code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way:

```
function ShowJQueryStandardDialog(searchTarget, title, width, height, closeFunction)
{
    $dialog = $('<div id="dialogDIV"><iframe id="dialogIFrame" frameborder="no" scrolling="auto" src="' + searchTarget + '" width="' + (width - 50) + 'px" height="' + (height - 50) + 'px"></iframe></div>');

    $dialog.dialog(
    {
        modal: true,
        title: title,
        show: 'slide',
        width: width,
        height: height,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        close: function (event, ui)
        {
            if (typeof closeFunction === 'function') closeFunction();
        }
    });

    /* IMPORTANT BIT */
    $(document).bind('close-dialog', function ()
    {
        $dialog.dialog('close');
    });
}
```

Then call `parent.$(parent.document).trigger('close-dialog');` when you want to close your dialog.